Want to filter same texts from 2 lists in google sheets
I have 2 lists One is equipments lists and other is summary of the equipments lists in one sheet
Summar list is sum of  equipments which are repeated,
like if you have chalks 2 no, chalks 2 no, duster 1no, board 3 no
summary list is chalk 4 no, duster 1 no, board 3no.
what i want is to check whether the equipment from the above list is mentioned in the summary list.
so if duster is not in summary list i want to find that out.
I thought of filtering but couldnt do it using =countif(C2:C50, c80:c40, C2)>1
=countif(C:C,C2)>1, i didnt how to do it..
I want to know whether below list has all the items as above list.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.
